# How to make this query run successfully?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select (SELECT * FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101'))) plant_cd from dual
```

returning

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
where or_in_list_fn returns
FV52
1101
```

I need Output

```
   Plant_cd
   ---------------
   FV52
   1101
```

Comment: Maybe this way `SELECT * FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101')` ?

Comment: No the plant_cd alias i need to use further..so i want to rewrite it..such that it returns
Plant_cd
FV52
1101

Comment: Recode your select statement as follows: `SELECT column_value as plant_cd FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52','1101'))`

Comment: The problem is: select (<some query that returns more than 1 row>) from dual This will always generate the mentioned exception: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Should "plant_cd" in your output be a column header, or a data item?

Comment: Here i dont have any column value.  I need to use the output from or_in_list_fn.and need to put column as plant_cd

Comment: @NevilleK:it shud b column header

Comment: NicholasKrasnov's solution doesn't work?

Comment: @Parado What column value i need to put there.bcos  i dont have any column value

Comment: So how can i modify this? I need to to have plant cd as a column header

Comment: The answer is in Nicholas Krasnov's comment under your question.

Comment: @SatheeshK `What column value i need to put there?` None. `column_value` is a pseudocolumn.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT column_value AS plant_cd FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101'))
```

Comment: Ops...  **Nicholas Krasnov** already had mentioned this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your subquery return 1 row and 1 field. You can use `max()`

```
select (SELECT max(yourfield) FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101'))) plant_cd from dual
```

Comment: I dont have any field .or_in_list_fn is a function it return fv52,1101 in a separate row..

Comment: @SatheeshK:If you're not doing anything in the outer SELECT ,then why your using a select statement inside another select USE.`SELECT   *
           FROM TABLE (or_in_list_fn ('FV52,1101'))` directly.Correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: @ Gaurav Soni: Because for alias name plant_cd

Answer (score 0):

Rather than returning the data from another select ,directly use the inner query ,because you are not doing anything in Outside Select

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101'))
```

If you want to do some filter in the outer select or join with another table then use it in from clause of the query as shown below:

```
select plant_cd.* from (SELECT * FROM TABLE(or_in_list_fn('FV52,1101'))) plant_cd
```